# Swift Universal framework issue on Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-framework

I have a swift framework and I use on objective c project. I create a fat framework with script. It works till Xcode 10.2.
I try to create fat framework on Xcode 10.2. It compiled successful but when I added on my objective-c project it not working on simulator.

Apple's release notes include my error but I didn't work. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes in known issues)

How can I create fat framework headers file for simulator?

Comment: Hi, to help you quickly can you please share your script here.

Comment: Please also add the error message instead of sharing document that includes that message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
https://gist.github.com/closerminds/8a8d8db6f87d2a65c4487f396f986737
This use the workaround proposed by Apple

Comment: It's ok to link to an answer but the answer must be minimally useful without the link.